# Matplotlib: Add a second legend to fake it as the plot title

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, titlebar, legend-properties

I have the following code which produces pie charts:

```
#Parameters
labels=['Ph 1', 'Ph 2','Ph 3']
colors = ['darkred', 'gold', 'green']
explode = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1) #Explode the all slices to make them more visible.

ph1=numpy.array([93.90,0.45,5.65]) 
ph2=numpy.array([82.96,0.86,16.17]) 
ph3=numpy.array([69.25,1.20,29.55])
fig1, (ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(3,1,subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
fig1.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
ph1 = mpatches.Patch(color='darkred', label='Ph 1')
ph2 = mpatches.Patch(color='gold', label='Ph 2')
ph3 = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Ph 3')
ax1.legend
ax2.legend(handles=[ph1, ph2, ph3], fontsize=10, loc=(-1.2, 0.3), prop={'size':10},shadow=True)
ax1.pie(ph1, labels=None, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%.2f')
ax2.pie(ph2, labels=None, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%.2f')
ax3.pie(ph3, labels=None, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%.2f')
ax1.text(1.1,0.4,'Ph 1, A=0.2', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
ax2.text(1.1,0.4,'Ph 2, B=0.3', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
ax3.text(1.1,0.4,'Ph 3, C=0.4', fontsize=8, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('fig.jpg',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

How can I insert a second legend in the top left corner, outside the plot area, where to put my title?

This is what I have now:

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you're looking for http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#placing-text-boxes

Comment: Yeah, but that is in axes coord. I would like the text box to stay outside the plot area.

Comment: use a transform (`transform=fig.transFigure`). See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add a figure-level title using `fig.suptitle` or `pyplot.suptitle`, perhaps with `horizontalalignment='left'`?

Comment: The original reasoning is that I wanted something like the legend, which is shaded.

Comment: You can add a box and shadow to a title.